# Getting the spliterator from a sorted stream throws an exception

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, spliterator

According to the doc of [`Spliterator#getComparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html#getComparator--), it states

> If this Spliterator's source is `SORTED` by a `Comparator`, returns that
>   `Comparator`. If the source is `SORTED` in natural order, returns null.
>   Otherwise, if the source is not `SORTED`, throws `IllegalStateException`.
>
> Implementation Requirements:
>
> The default implementation always throws `IllegalStateException`.
>
> Returns: a `Comparator`, or `null` if the elements
>   are sorted in the natural order.
>
> Throws: `IllegalStateException` - if
>   the spliterator does not report a characteristic of `SORTED`.

So when running this piece of code

```
Spliterator<Integer> spliterator = Stream.of(1, 2, 3).sorted().spliterator();

System.out.println((spliterator.characteristics() & Spliterator.SORTED) == Spliterator.SORTED);
System.out.println(spliterator.getComparator());
```

I get:

```
true
null
```

So far so good. Now when doing this:

```
Spliterator<Integer> spliterator = Stream.of(1, 2, 3).sorted(Comparator.naturalOrder()).spliterator();

System.out.println((spliterator.characteristics() & Spliterator.SORTED) == Spliterator.SORTED);
System.out.println(spliterator.getComparator());
```

It outputs `false` and throws an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$AbstractWrappingSpliterator.getComparator(StreamSpliterators.java:259)
    at SpliteratorTest.main(SpliteratorTest.java:10)
```

Why does it outputs false and throws an exception?

Shouldn't it give me the `Comparator` I supplied to `sorted()`, according to the documentation?

(This happens also with `reverseOrder()`, or `comparing(identity())`, etc.).

Comment: By the way, you can use `spliterator.hasCharacteristics(Spliterator.SORTED)`

Comment: I found a [related discussion](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2014-June/027421.html) in the mail archives, however I'm not convinced by [Paul Santoz's answer](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2014-June/027423.html). Why would a stream from a `TreeSet` with a custom comparator be `SORTED` and a stream sorted with the same custom comparator would not?

Comment: @Didier L: that’s indeed not convincing. Especially the “we don't know if two comparators are identical in their behaviour” part. Of course, there might be two different comparators exhibiting the same behavior without a way to recognize it, but that is not a reason to ignore the fact that two identical comparators, of course, exhibit the same behavior. Especially as both, `Comparator.naturalOrder()==Comparator.naturalOrder()` and `Comparator.reverseOrder()==Comparator.reverseOrder()`, evaluate to `true`.

Answer (score 1):

Internally streams are using `StreamOpFlag` enum which is somewhat different from spliterator flags. Flags are converted using the `java.util.stream.StreamOpFlag.fromCharacteristics(Spliterator<?>)` method which implementation is the following:

```
static int fromCharacteristics(Spliterator<?> spliterator) {
    int characteristics = spliterator.characteristics();
    if ((characteristics & Spliterator.SORTED) != 0 && spliterator.getComparator() != null) {
        // Do not propagate the SORTED characteristic if it does not correspond
        // to a natural sort order
        return characteristics & SPLITERATOR_CHARACTERISTICS_MASK & ~Spliterator.SORTED;
    }
    else {
        return characteristics & SPLITERATOR_CHARACTERISTICS_MASK;
    }
}
```

Seems that internally the `SORTED` characteristic for the spliterator which is not explicitly natural ordered is unnecessary for the stream API, so it's not preserved. Actually it's never specified in the documentation that `sorted(comparator).spliterator()` *must* return the spliterator with `SORTED` characteristic. The spliterator documentation says that if it has `SORTED` characteristic, it must return the comparator, but there's no case when having the `SORTED` characteristic is required, thus it's up to implementation. This can change in future, but it's not a bug.

**Update:** just noticed that in JDK-9 there's a clear statement [added](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/jdk9/jdk/rev/9ee4b68456b6) into the documentation of `spliterator()` method:

> The returned spliterator should report the set of characteristics derived from the stream pipeline (namely the characteristics derived from the stream source spliterator and the intermediate operations). Implementations may report a sub-set of those characteristics.  For example, it may be too expensive to compute the entire set for some or all possible stream pipelines.

See the [JDK-8048689](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8048689) bug report.

Comment: I wouldn’t say that the `SORTED` characteristic is *unnecessary* for the stream API when a comparator is used, it’s just a huge flaw of the current implementation that it treats the use of explicit comparators as a second class sorting. Even using `Comparator.naturalOrder()` may have a performance drop over using `sorted()` without a comparator (and without compile-time type safety)…

Comment: @Holger, well I mean for current implementation it's unnecessary. Surely the implementation must be improved at least to detect the `Comparator.naturalOrder()`.

Answer (score 0):

**I think this is a bug in Oracle JDK (1.8.0_45).**

When you make a stream sorted using natural order with `Stream#sorted()`, it internally wraps the stream in a `SortedOps.OfRef` using the following constructor:

```
    OfRef(AbstractPipeline<?, T, ?> upstream) {
        super(upstream, StreamShape.REFERENCE,
              StreamOpFlag.IS_ORDERED | StreamOpFlag.IS_SORTED);
    ...
```

When you give a custom `Comparator` with `Stream#sorted(Comparator)`, it does the same but uses the following constructor instead:

```
    OfRef(AbstractPipeline<?, T, ?> upstream, Comparator<? super T> comparator) {
        super(upstream, StreamShape.REFERENCE,
              StreamOpFlag.IS_ORDERED | StreamOpFlag.NOT_SORTED);
    ...
```

The `StreamOpFlag.NOT_SORTED` is intended to clear the `SORTED` flag, in case it was previously set. This means that a sorted stream will become a non-sorted stream after this operation.

I think it might have been misused in place of `StreamOpFlag.IS_SORTED` and the `super()` call should use the same parameters as in the first constructor.

I couldn't find a corresponding issue in the Java Bug System though.